# How can I deselect the node or set the myTreeView.SelectedNode to null?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, treeview, treenode, system.web.ui.webcontrols

I am working on an online web application written in C# and I am using  System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView

The treeview is represented by an asp:TreeView tag embedded on the webpage.

its weird, I'm using .NET Framework 4, and if I try something like

```
myTreeView.SelectedNode = null
```

then it states " cannot be assigned to -- it is read-only"

Could you please assist?  How can I deselect the node or set the 
    myTreeView.SelectedNode 
to null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code that I used to ensure that the SelectedNode was Deselected:

```
if (myTreeView.SelectedNode != null)
{
    myTreeView.SelectedNode.Selected = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Works too

```
if (myTreeView.SelectedNode.IsSelected)
{
    myTreeView.SelectedNode = null;
}
```